# Performance issue : canvas seems to be redrawing on addition of every Path

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, paperjs

I see performance issue when lot of path points are added. When there are far too little points, the curves are very smooth. However when canvas has added moderate number of points the curves seems to become sharp because of performance impact. I noticed the paper js clears the entire canvas and draws the view again on every paper.view.update call. This update call is called on every mouse event.
Here is the summary of my application --

1. canvas assigns mouse event listenenrs
2. onMouseDown - paper.Path is initialized
3. onMouseMove - a point is plotted using paper.Point
4. onMouseUp -  the path is simplfied and smoothen.

Here is the snippet of the code I debugged in  full version of paperjs.  line - 11578 onwards

```
CanvasView :

update: function(force) {
        var project = this._project;
        if (!project || !force && !project._needsUpdate)
            return false;
        var ctx = this._context,
            size = this._viewSize;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, size.width + 1, size.height + 1);
        project.draw(ctx, this._matrix, this._pixelRatio);
        project._needsUpdate = false;
        return true;
    }
```

This update method is called by paper js.

As number of points grow, the performance is extremely degraded. How can I improve this to make it acceptable performance?
I have asked the similar question on paperjs forum [PaperJS forum question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/paperjs/eF6cF6yOjWQ/)

Comment: Well, you are calling `clearRect` which clears the canvas every frame, so you have to re-draw it, otherwise it will be empty.

Comment: @Cristy This is not my code. This is the snippet from paperj source code. It calls this update method on every point I add in the path. When there are lot of points on canvas the redrawing is incredibly slow.

Comment: Cristy has your answer: The canvas is being cleared and the updated points-path is redrawn with every mousemove === sloooow! A much better method is to add a new stroke to the new point upon every mousemove. I don't know paperJS that well, but see if there is an option to sketch your points-path this way. If not, you're stuck in slow motion.

Comment: @markE The problem is paperjs registers mouse listeners and calls this update method on adding a new point/segment. So I understand that performance problem can be solved if I just redraw the segment and not redraw the whole canvas. What I don't know is how to do it. PaperJS always does this work and not in my control or is it? 
I am not doing anything special here. I have registered mouse listeners and add points on mouse move thats it!.

Comment: I'm not a PaperJS guru which is why I suggested that you search their API for a way to incrementally draw your point set rather than constantly redrawing it from scratch.